# Change qwerty to numeric keypad in Android Custom keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I am trying to make an Android keyboard for the Sinhala language. So I followed [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) and finally I got my keyboard as below picture.

Now I need to change the Sinhala keyboard to a numeric keypad once I click the 123 button on the Sinhala keyboard. I searched in Google and followed lot of tutorials and Github projects.. but I can't understand how it is implemented. Please anyone help solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Name your 123 key with code eg -2 (mode chande code)

```
<Key android:codes="-2" android:keyLabel="123"/>
```

and then demand action for it into your SimpleIME.java file `onKey` method

```
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_MODE_CHANGE:
            keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.number);
            kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
            kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
            break;
```

Ofcourse use your own number.xml file name in here

```
Keyboard(this, R.xml.number);
```